# How can i allow both IP Address and URL in django field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I want to allow both **flutterdemo.hp.com** and **12.135.720.12** in django field.

This is what i tried.

```
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets
from django.core.validators import URLValidator

class FlutterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    fqdn_ip = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100, validators =[URLValidator])
```

But it is allowing all the text and just working as CharFiled. URLField is treating "flutterdemo.hp.com" as invalid.

How can i achieve this?
Thanks,

Comment: `URLValidator` also checks for the URL scheme(http, https, ftp, ftps) etc. so the validation would fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this third-party library for Validating URL and IP.

Validate Ipv4 Ip [here](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-validators.ip_address)

Validate Ipv6 Ip [here](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#ipv6)

Validate Url [here](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-validators.url)

After validate you can save with `CharField`